# Improve performance of foreach inside another foreach

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
<?php
$episodios = $SQL->query("SELECT * FROM episodios order by id desc LIMIT 500");
$temporadas = $SQL->query("SELECT * from temporadas");

foreach($episodios as $episodio) {              
    //review performance
    foreach($temporadas as $temporada) {
        if ($episodio['url_anime'] == $temporada['url_anime'] && $episodio['temporada'] == $temporada['temporada']) {
            $tempName = (($temporada['showname'] == 1) ? '- '.$temporada['nome'].'' : '');
        }
    } 
}
?>
```

But i'm worried about the code performance, because this loop inside another..

Someone told me to use cache and only update when get new data, but have other way to do the same thing with better performance? this code is displayed on my home website page.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How many rows does your database have?

Comment: You can use JOIN statements in these kind of cases 
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: hi @kanohn , check this query: "SELECT * from temporadas join episodios on temporadas.url_anime==episodios.url_anime and temporadas.temporada==episodios.temporada"

Comment: Could you help me with JOIN? my database have more than 10k rows in episodios table, and 500 rows in temporadas table..

Comment: @MohammadRezaAbbasi I just leave the same code and only change the query?

Comment: ok, add Answers

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below query for improve code performance:-

```
$tempName = $SQL->query("Select temporadas.nome from temporadas INNER JOIN episodios ON 
  temporadas.url_anime = episodios.url_anime AND temporadas.temporada = 
  episodios.temporada WHERE temporadas.nome = 1 LIMIT  500");
```

Answer (score 0):

pls check

```
<?php
//with code
$episodios = $SQL->query("SELECT * FROM episodios order by id desc LIMIT 500");
$temporadas = $SQL->query("SELECT * from temporadas");

$items = [];
foreach ($episodios as $episodio) {
    if (!isset($items[$episodio['url_anime'] . "||" . $episodio['temporada']])) {
        $items[$episodio['url_anime'] . "||" . $episodio['temporada']] = "-";
    }
}

foreach ($temporadas as $temporada) {
    if (isset($items[$temporada['url_anime'] . "||" . $temporada['temporada']])) {
        $items[$temporada['url_anime'] . "||" . $temporada['temporada']] = (($temporada['showname'] == 1) ? '- ' . $temporada['nome'] . '' : '');
    }
}

var_dump($items);

//There is a possibility of a minor error because I have real data



//or with query
#"SELECT * from temporadas join episodios on temporadas.url_anime==episodios.url_anime and temporadas.temporada==episodios.temporada"
```